# Blank page in browser with Unexpected token '<' in console

Tags: heroku, deployment, strapi

I have a problem with deploying Strapi application on Heroku. Both local and Heroku Strapi setups are using Postgres database.

Can't see any errors in Heroku logs, just a blank page in browser. Brpwser's console has these two errors:

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'    runtime~main.8073a043.js:1
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'    main.abbe0ac9.chunk.js:1

Heroku logs:

2020-12-11T15:26:03.986177+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-12-11T15:26:03.916838+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Accepting connections at http://localhost:58777
2020-12-11T15:26:04.470749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=john-strapi-postgres.herokuapp.com request_id=8783501f-3d9f-4986-bb44-6648a93d8105 fwd="68.82.27.99" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=304 bytes=85 protocol=https
2020-12-11T15:26:04.561029+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/runtime~main.8073a043.js" host=john-strapi-postgres.herokuapp.com request_id=008157f5-a2ff-4738-9a8c-8ef4ac76a2d8 fwd="68.82.27.99" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=85 protocol=https
2020-12-11T15:26:04.558537+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/main.abbe0ac9.chunk.js" host=john-strapi-postgres.herokuapp.com request_id=aa2e15a8-e001-4333-a195-f669ddcaac74 fwd="68.82.27.99" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=85 protocol=https
2020-12-11T15:26:04.666249+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=john-strapi-postgres.herokuapp.com request_id=f2342dac-0347-4b0b-a4e4-89f0a425a98a fwd="68.82.27.99" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=85 protocol=https

Local Strapi application runs perfectly fine.

- Node v. 14.5.1
- NPM v. 6.14.8
- Strapi v. 3.3.4
- Windows 10

Comment: same error but on my case, admin(frontend) is deployed to AWS S3/Cloudfront/Route53 stack